# Symfony parameters in environment variable not found

Tags: php, symfony

I am on Symfony 2.8.12
This is my `parameters.yml` file:

```
parameters:
    database_host: localhost
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: test
    database_user: root
    secret: TODO
```

I have my environment variable `SYMFONY__DATABASE_PASSWORD` equal to `root`
If I run `app/console debug:container --parameter="database_password"` I have

```
 ------------------- -------
  Parameter           Value
 ------------------- -------
  database_password   root
 ------------------- -------
```

But when I go to localhost/app_dev.php I have

```
ParameterNotFoundException in ParameterBag.php line 84:
You have requested a non-existent parameter "database_password". Did you mean this: "database_port"?
```

Same thing after purging the cache

Doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html

Comment: in your parameters: there is no database_password defined

Comment: why `database_password` is not in your parameters.yml ?

Comment: Because it's defined via SYMFONY__DATABASE_PASSWORD and if I add one the environment variable will not override it

Comment: yeah but where are you calling it ?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html

Comment: you mean this `SetEnv          SYMFONY__DATABASE__PASSWORD secret` ?

Comment: Yes `SYMFONY__DATABASE__PASSWORD` is equal to 'root' on my server

Comment: which web server are you using? how did you set the environment variables?

Comment: I think it's not to be se inside parameters.yml but inside config.yml: doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        dbname:   symfony_project
        user:     '%database.user%'
        password: '%database.password%'

Comment: for the CLI is ok, now check for the webserver (apache o nginx) and check that you have restarted the web server. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

If using `phpinfo()` and `php -i` the variable appears in `$_ENV[]` 
(that is to say the environment variables are not merged with the ones from the server) try to add this line in `app_dev.php`

```
$_SERVER = array_merge($_SERVER, $_ENV);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should 'export' the shell variable. Type:

export SYMFONY__DATABASE__PASSWORD='root'

Comment: It's already exported, `echo $SYMFONY__DATABASE_PASSWORD` returns the good value